# Is there a library to use Amazon IoT services on any Arduino?

Tags: web-service

I started to work with AWS IoT today, which offers a MQTT based connection to their web service. They officially only have a demo for the Arduino Yún, which is rather expensive. Has someone managed to get it running (e.g. with a NodeMCU with a ESP8266)?

Comment: Any comments from the downvoter?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the AWS IoT Embedded C SDK, that is for more general devices.
Other Arduinos requires a crypto library and a device powerful enough, maybe PI, to support the authentication process...
At this time they have no crypto library like the YUN SDK, for other Arduinos...

[Try it...](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/blob/master/README.md)